# Column-width breaks divs in Chrome

Tags: html, css

Chrome breaks divs instead of enlarging the outer container in column-width block.

One pixel more of width solves the issue. As does another list-item. How can this be avoided?

A fiddle is available here https://fiddle.jshell.net/papa_bravo/01dzhwpz/

```css
.my-list {
  border: 1px red solid;
  column-width: 70px;
  width: 226px;
}

.my-item {
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-list">
  <div class="my-item">Test1</div>
  <div class="my-item">Test2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work if you remove the `float: left;` of the .my-item-class.

Comment: I can only guess. The floating seems to interfere with the column-alignment and mix up the behaviours.
If you add a third column, the three divs float in a row instead of distributing into columns.Columns also are not completely supported according to http://caniuse.com/#search=column-width.